# Magento Change Product URL

Tags: php, magento

Is there a way to modify or prepend the product url? We are working on a large website (500  Iproducts), and I think it becomes quite cluttered to have them all "in" the root directory. I would like to organize things a bit better, in this case, putting `products/` in the url before the product key.

What would you recommend as the cleanest and best way to prepend "products/" into the url key? I wanted to see if there were any suggestions here before I rolled my sleeves up and got working on some overrides. I have tried setting the URL key to be that, but, naturally, it strips the `/` for a `-`. I figured that would happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's going to be tricky to pull off.  The URLs for products, as well as products-by-categories are generated somewhere deep in the indexing system.  When you save a product or category being the scenes, the re-indexing that kicks off includes tasks that generate a number of `core/url_rewrite` models, stored in the `core_url_rewrite` table.   These models are what make the "SEO Friendly" urls.  So you'd need to find that code, and add your custom logic there to generate the correct rewrite models

**Then** you'd need to check the URL helpers to ensure they were generating the correct URLs.  I'm not sure if these methods consult the rewrite table (which would be good), or if they act with foreknowledge abou how Magento's URLs would be structured).

Good luck.

Comment: if the helper uses [`getUrl()`](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/reference/geturl_function_parameters) with a `_use_rewrite` option then the rewrite table is consulted. I'm confident the catalog helpers are doing this already.

Comment: Thank you for your help! It looks like I'll have my work cut out for me :).

Answer (score 0):

To add the products into products/ you would need to create a category named 'products' and then move your product under there.  This would be time consuming but cleaner in the long run for /admin.  The URL rewrite index will always change the / to a - otherwise.  But Magento will always create your product under the root path as it better for SEO.  It might be a good idea to create a category structure deeper than that.  I have been working for stores of over 500k items.

Comment: I second that. In addition, after you put your product into categories you can revert to domain.com/product-url at any time using System/Configuration/Catalog/Search Engine Optimizations -> Use Categories Path for Product URLs

Answer (score 0):

Go to app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Url.php and then go to the function _refreshProductRewrite
This function updates de products URL when Reindexing Data.

In the function, when constructing the array $rewriteData, change:
'request_path'  => $requestPath,
to:
'request_path'  => 'products/'.$requestPath,

This will change the product URL when creating the product, and when reindexing data for the old products.

Comment: An error occurred while saving the URL rewrite error occurs
Doesnt work