# Magento Product URL with category

Tags: php, magento

i have here my code. i get the complete url path of a product then redirect it but the problems are:

i've got this error "The webpage has a redirect loop"

my problem everytime performs this code and redirect to complete url, this code run everytime the url redirect until the webpage has a redirect loop.

anyone can help me to my problem.

For Example:

User access this url
http://www.url.com/product.html

then it will redirect to this url
http://www.url.com/category/product.html

until i got the error "redirect loop"

i want to get if the url has category then it will not perform this code.

```
$product_id = $this->getProduct()->getId();
$_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($product_id);


if($_product->getStatus()==1){


   $_categories = $_product->getCategoryIds();
   $_category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($_categories[0]);

   $url = $this->getUrl($_category->getUrlPath()).$_product->getUrlPath();
   $url = str_replace(".html","" ,$url) . '.html';

    header('Location: ' . $url);
    die();

}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I see from the code that you are not checking if the category name is already in the url, and stopping the redirection, because of which the browser is showing the redirection loop.

You can also try redirection using the .htaccess file instead of php redirects.

There is already some content available on magento product urls. [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7405720/magento-change-product-url) & [External](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/6781/mass-change-product-url-keys-to-match-product-names)